# How to solve nonlinear recurrence relation (quadratic)

Tags: recurrence-relations

Please help me solve this weird recurrence relation. This is not really standard quadratic, so I'm totally confused. I tried with logarithm (but 8 is excess), tried writing this recurrence in one degree up or down... I cannot sleep for days because of this :-( This is what troubles me:$$a_{n+2}a_{n}=a_{n+1}^2+8$$for$$a_1=4$$and$$a_2=6$$
Please just give idea or complete solution (step by step) - I'm desperate!(I don't know how write square, so please edit. Thanks.)

Comment: What is $a_n a_{n+2} - a_{n+1}^2$ if $a_n = B^n + C^n?$

Comment: That way is almost good enough; what, precisely, is $a_n a_{n+2} - a_{n+1}^2$ if $a_n = \beta B^n + \gamma C^n? $ Then,  how do you get $a_n a_{n+2} - a_{n+1}^2$ to become constant?

Comment: Sigh; got to sleep, evidently. This type of relationship is discussed in Conway and Guy, The Book of Numbers. Probably chapter 3, and called a Number Wall.

Comment: @willjagy I am still up and listening my friend.