# Quadratic recurrence relation (from a math-contest)

Tags: recurrence-relations, contest-math

It's given the following quadratic relation: $$a_n = \frac{a_{n-1}^2+61}{a_{n-2}}$$ Find $a_{10}$. Note that I can't use a calculator or a computer, instead I was wondering if there's a trick to find it. What can you suggest ?

($a_1 = 7$, $a_2 = 11$)

Comment: What are the first two values ($a_0$ and $a_1$ or $a_1$ and $a_2$)?

Comment: @Nitin I edited

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1285600/how-to-solve-nonlinear-recurrence-relation-quadratic) might be related. There is no answer but insightful comments by Will Jagy.

Answer (score 1):

Sequence $a_n$ satisfies a linear recurrence of order 2.

Comment: How did you notice that?

Comment: From having solved the same problem with other values of 61.

Comment: It might be $a_n = 3a_{n-1} - a_{n-2}$

Comment: Can I prove this is true for all $n$ ?

Comment: Yes, it is true for all $n$ and an induction would work.